# Cant override get_queryset with group by expression in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to override get queryset method to display the total amount of orders with such status, order_unit

```
@admin.register(models.OrderSummary)
class OrderSummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # change_list_template = 'admin/order_summary_change_list.html'
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    show_full_result_count = False
    list_display = (
        "order_unit",  #ForeignKey
        "status",      #ForeignKey
    )
    list_filter = (
        ('created', DateRangeFilter),
        ('order_unit__name', MultiSelectFilter),
        ('status__name', MultiSelectFilter),
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs: QuerySet = super().get_queryset(request)
        grouped_by_status_and_name = qs.values('status__name', 'order_unit__name')\
            .annotate(total=Count('id')).order_by('order_unit__name')

        x = str(grouped_by_status_and_name.query)
        return grouped_by_status_and_name
```

But this is falls with **TypeError("Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list()")**
Adding select_related_field helps, but i need to group by. Combination of this two(select_rel and values() is disallowed). How can I do this?

PS: I am on Django 3.1

Comment: Please share `OrderSummary`  model code

Comment: why you want to group by on `status__name`, `order_unit__name` fields? You can apply group by on `status_id` , `order_unit_id` fields.

Comment: Don't use `.values(...)`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then how can i group by, without .values?

Comment: @MdShahbazAhmad it matters?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to access the string representation of related fields `order_unit` and `status` in `list_display` and your queryset returns a list of dicts, So Django gives the error TypeError ("Cannot call select_related() after.values() or.values_list()") because queryset applies join with related models to access object name.

```
qs = OrderSummary.objects.select_related("status", "order_unit").filter(status__name="fail").values("status__name", "order_unit__name").annotate(total_count=Count("id"))
```

The above query has no issues. You can apply join with related models, apply filters to the resultset, and also apply grouping to the resultset.

But if you use the **admin default change_list template**, then this query gives you an **error**. Because django admin expects a list of objects in queryset when rendering values in templates, and group_by query returns a list of dicts in queryset.

If you want to use the above query, then you **override the change_list template and render the data itself.**

I assume the Status and OrderUnit models have limited records. You do not need to join related models; without joining, your page load time will be reduced.

```
@admin.register(models.OrderSummary)
class OrderSummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    change_list_template = 'admin/order_summary_change_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.values("status_id", "order_unit_id").annotate(total_count=Count("id"))
        return qs

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        # you can access in status_dict and order_unit_dict and render name of status and order_unit
        extra_context['status_dict'] = self.get_status_data()
        extra_context['order_unit_dict'] = self.get_order_unit_data()

        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    def get_status_data(self):
        return {item['id']: item['name'] for item in Status.objects.all().values('id', 'name')}


    def get_order_unit_data(self):
        return {item['id']: item['name'] for item in OrderUnit.objects.all().values('id', 'name')}
```

You can also improve the list_filter query set.